# Can I copy an event in the gnome-calendar?

Tags: 22.04, gnome-calendar

On Mac, one can just Copy-Paste an event in the Apple Calendar (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS), and I am looking for the equivalent option in gnome-calendar, if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. As you can see here https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-calendar/-/issues/429 this feature is still under discussion but not yet implemented.

Comment: it is possible in evolution (ctrl-c, ctrl-v), and yes, useful indeed.